# how set a textView in ADT android?

Tags: android, textview, adt, settext

i am beginner in android,and i write this code in ADT v22.6.2:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    //this is my code
    TextView tbx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbxName);
    tbx.setText("H.H");
}
```

but when i launch program -> Unfortunately,app has stopped

Edit:

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
android:id="@+id/container" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.example.t.MainActivity" 
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" > 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tbx" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="" />
 \</FrameLayout>
```

please help me.
thanks

Comment: TextView tbx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbxName);
    tbx .setText("H.H"); will work

Comment: Is your `TextView` inside `activity_main` layout ? Please post your logcat error also.

Comment: yes,it is in the activity_main

Comment: @user3338477 post `activity_main.xml`. could be wrong reference of id

Comment: @user3338477 post your stacktrace also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` is not initialized anywhere. You have only initialize `tbx` and also there is a possibility that `TextView` belongs to `PlaceholderFragment`.

Edit:

Form your comment you say you have `tbx.setText("H.H");`

Likely the textview belongs to fragment and you should initialize textview in  `PlaceholderFragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    TextView tbx = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tbxName);
    tbx.setText("H.H");
    return rootView;
}
```

Edit 2:

You problem has nothing to do with `ADT v22.6.2`. You are probably getting `NullPointerException`

You reference wrong id .

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tbx"
```

Change this

```
 TextView tbx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbxName);
```

to

```
 TextView tbx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbx);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly given the id of your `TextView`.

Just change your `TextView` id from `R.id.tbxName` to `R.id.tbx` as its given in your layout.

Instead of

```
TextView tbx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbxName);
```

Change it

```
  TextView tbx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbx);
```